# How can I determine why my A/C runs all day?

Tags: insulation, hvac, air-conditioning

I have a Bryant AC/Furnace unit.  My house is 10 years old.  A heat wave hit this weekend & temps got up to 95°F outside.  I had my thermostat set to 75°, and it ran all day.  The thermostat never dropped below 80° during the day & eventually cooled down towards the evening.  How can I tell if it's a problem with my AC or with the insulation in the house?  The attic has insulation "blown" in it, and from what I can tell, was done recently before we bought the house 5 years ago.

Does the "blown" insulation have to be re-blown every so often?  Or is it more likely a problem with the AC unit?  I've never had it serviced since I bought the house, but I have changed the air filters monthly.

*Edit*

Something else I remembered:  my house is bi-level.  I keep the downstairs vents closed because if they're all open, it gets pretty cold down there.  With them closed, it's maybe a little warmer than upstairs.  We're upstairs most of the time anyway.  Would that affect anything?

Comment: How many square feet is the conditioned space? What size is the A/C unit? How thick/deep is the insulation?

Comment: Sounds like your A/C is underpowered and/or your house is under-insulated/weatherproofed

Comment: Well when I bought the house, it cooled pretty well.  It wasn't until maybe last year it started getting worse.

Comment: If it's worked in the past well in similar weather, then I'd check a) your air filters inside and b) the fins outside [clean them if necessary].

Comment: Do you have an air return on your upper level?

Comment: Yes, two vents in the partition separating the living room and the kitchen.  They're higher up & the vents point up.  Should they be pointing down?

Comment: Whether the return vents point up or down won't matter as long as they're not blocked by anything. When you close the vents in the lower level, you should notice an increased airflow from the vents in the upper level. Are you seeing this increase?

Comment: It's hard to tell regarding the increase now because I've done it for years & I couldn't compare to what it was before when it was working better.

Comment: You don't need to compare it to how it was when the AC was working better, just re-open the vents on the lower level temporarily and see if there's less flow on the upper level vents while the fan is running. If there isn't a noticeable difference, it would indicate an issue with your ducting or fan.

Comment: How many square feet is the conditioned space? What size is the A/C unit? How thick/deep is the insulation?

Comment: Hang on - are we clear on what I mean by air return?  They need to *suck* air, not blow it...

Comment: And yes I know how that sounds... ;)

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I was clear, but I can see how it may be confusing. In my comments, I always used "vents" meaning the "blowing" kind for the conditioned air. I used "return vents" (or should have just said "return") for the "sucking" kind. I took the comment from churnd as understanding you properly since he mentioned them as "higher up" on the wall which is typical for an air return (and the direction the louvers point doesn't matter for a return since it's not really protecting it from rain or anything inside the house; it wouldn't affect airflow either way).

Comment: Ok - just making sure. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your question almost exactly sums up the situation I had at my home last August.

What I found then was that despite a properly sized air conditioning unit and what I believe to be good insulation (the house holds heat well during the winter), the unit still couldn't keep up.

I don't have full proof, but I think a few factors caused my situation and might be worth checking for you:

1. The condenser (outdoor unit) sits in an "inside corner" with the house on two sides of it and a chimney and small storage shed that partially blocks a third side of it. This prevents good airflow across the unit. [I can't do anything about this without relocating the unit, which is not a DIY job for me.]
2. We had very little wind at all during the heat wave, which also added to the lack of airflow across the condenser.
3. The condenser was visibly dirty, which makes heat transfer to the outdoor air less efficient. Lots of dirt, dust, pollen, grass clippings, etc. build up on the fins over time. Normally rain will clean it off somewhat, but we hadn't had rain in ages.

Despite [some advice](http://home.howstuffworks.com/how-to-maintain-an-air-conditioner2.htm) I've seen not to do it, I used a garden hose to wash off the fins of the condenser (it gets wet from rain, right?) very gently, taking care not to make it full of mud or to bend the fins.

I could see water evaporating immediately on contact, and I have an infrared thermometer I used that showed a 30F or so drop in temperature in short order. The AC performed much better after that, but we also started to get a gentle breeze that helped things along.

Comment: Another thing on the condenser is that fins and kids don't mix.  If the fins are all mashes together that could affect cooling also.  If that is the problems then take a wire brush and lightly brush the fins till they seperate.

Comment: There are a few spots on the fins where they're mashed together, the biggest being the size of a quarter.  I wouldn't think it was a lot of them.  The condensor itself sits in an open area in the shade so it stays cool I would think.  I did wash it off with a hose (no nozzle) for about 15 mins so I guess we'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The easy answer is because your thermostat is telling it to run all day.  So, should it or should it not be?  Is the thermostat in a good position in the house?  If it's directly in the path of a sunbeam, then it will get hot and run more than necessary to cool the rest of the the house down.  Is there enough cool air coming out each of the vents?  If you close most of the vents, do the remaining ones have a stronger air force?  If not, you might be leaking some air out of the ducts.  If your A/C unit is 10 years old and has not been serviced in at least the past 5 years, it's probably worth the money for an inspection/service.  This shouldn't be terribly expensive and is a good starting point.  Monthly air filter changes also sounds like a little excessive to me.  Also:  Check for a second air filter if it's an older system.  I was surprised to find a second one in my unit and promptly changed it.

Comment: I think the thermostat is fine.  It used to run more efficient than it does now.  I guess I was just looking for reasons why that may be & hopefully fix it myself.  I did find another filter inside the unit & took it out for a bit to see if that'd help but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is the first answer to mention having someone out to look at the coolant level in your system. Having someone out to check every few years is generally highly recommended. It's basic maintenance that can save you from expensive problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Another likely problem is that your system needs the coolant recharged.  If the coolant is low, there is not enough to cool the air as it passes through the coil.  You may have a leak somewhere, but the house is cooling somewhat, so the system is not empty.  Regardless, call a qualified A/C person to service the unit.